# Use/fetch sql data in a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, database

fetch data from sql and store it in javascript variable. i already have phpmyadmin connected to my website. i am trying to get two variables (date) from my sql table.

JAVSCRIPT:

```
var countdown_48 = new Date;

countdown_48.setHours( countdown_48.getHours() + 48 );

var x = setInterval(function() {

  var now = new Date().getTime();

  var distance = countdown_48 - now;
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  document.querySelectorAll('.c_countdown').forEach(function(elem){
    elem.innerHTML = innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
  })

  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("c_countdown").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
```

trying to get the two sql values in var ("createddate and expiration date")

SQL:

[image: table]

Comment: Try to use Ajax to fetch data from PHP code

Answer (score 0):

just use the php variable into your javascript var if your js code in php page

e.g.

```
<?php //connection file 
$sql="SELECT createddate, expiration FROM table WHERE id=1"; $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql); $row=mysqli_fetch_arrary($result); $var=$row['createddate']; $var2=$row['expiration']; ?>
    <script>
    var created = <?php echo $var; ?>
    var expire= <?php echo $var2; ?>
    </script>
```

Comment: I guess you have to add ```quotes``` in ```php statement```.```var a = '<?php echo $var; ?>';```

Comment: i see the logic in the answer, but i need to get the data from my sql table

Answer (score 0):

i am non PHP guy but what you can do here is using select query get data from table

```
$sql = "SELECT column1, column2 FROM chartdata";
```

here is how you can push your data in a object

```
$data = array();
while($enr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $a = array($enr['column1'], $enr['column2']);
    array_push($data, $a);
}
```

this is how you can use it in javascript

```
$.ajax({
   url : 'serv.php', // your php file
   type : 'GET', // type of the HTTP request
   success : function(data){
      var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
      console.log(obj);
   }
});
```